# Why is slice not slicing an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slice

I've used slice for awhile now with no issue, my problem lies with .slice() not slicing.
Code: (why does it smash the code??)

```
let data 
data = await Models.find().sort([['points', 'descending']]) 
console.log(data.length) // output: 179 
data.slice(0,5) 
console.log(data.length) // output: 179
```

Here is what data returns as:

> {
> points: 100,
> commandsUsed: 0,
> tipDifficulty: 'Not Set.',
> mapDifficulty: 'Not Set.',
> stateDifficulty: 'Not Set.',
> gameType: 'Not Set.',
> items: [],
> _id: 623d29b01fde8a4b347eadb7,
> difficulty: 'Not Set.',
> userID: '1234567890',
> serverID: '1234567890',
> __v: 0
> },

Repeated over and over again (179 times)

I've tried splice(), .filter() but splice should work, it always has before(discord js 12).

Comment: Step 1: Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice): _“The `slice` method returns a [shallow copy](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy) of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from `start` to `end` (`end` not included) where `start` and `end` represent the index of items in that array. **The original array will not be modified.**”_. Please, get in the habit of making “Ask a question on Stack Overflow” your “step _last_”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.slice(0,5)` does not modify the input array `data`.  Instead, it returns a new array with a shallow copy of the selected elements:

```
let results = data.slice(0,5);
console.log(results.length);  // 5 (assuming data contained more than 5 elements)
```

Used correctly, `.splice()` will modify the input array by either deleting elements or inserting elements.